# Checking if it is equal, Normal int and #define macro. but it doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have an iVar named,

```
int DATA_IN_TRANSIT;
```

and I have defined several macros, e.g.

```
#define PLACES 0;
```

When I do something like the following,

```
if(DATA_IN_TRANSIT == PLACES)
{
   NSLog(@"Make LLVM Dance!");
}
```

I get a compiler error (`expression expected`) in the line `if(DATA_IN_TRANSIT == PLACES)`

I don't know why it's giving me an error? Am I doing something naive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define PLACES 0
```

but without ';'

otherwise you'll get

```
if(DATA_IN_TRANSIT == 0;)
{
   NSLog(@"Make LLVM Dance!");
}
```